# Running git with higher memory allocation

Tags: memory, git, ulimit

I am facing memory/data segment issues while running git. However, if I set my ulimits to  a bit higher like below.

```
ulimit -m 262144

ulimit -d 262144
```

It runs fine. Don't we have anyway to allocate more memory/data segment while running git commands.

Comment: By default those should be `unlimited`, so perhaps you are on a system where limits have been configured.  You could just add `ulimit -m unlimited` & `ulimit -d unlimited` to `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: yeah..but I want more is to run git with some memory options. I'll be playing with system security stuffs if I set parameters to unlimited.

Comment: Limiting (or not limiting) those particular fields is not really a security issue.  If the administration really does not want you to exceed a certain value, it will have a hard limit set, and you need superuser permissions to change that.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` will do exactly what you want. It can limit just a single program name, thus will not impact 'global' settings the way ulimit will.

Run the manpage:  `man limits.conf`

Comment: This is a great answer. But doesn't solve my problem as I don't have access to /etc/security folder.

Comment: Make a request of the system admin to put the entry in for you. It's okay if an admin has to do work now and then ;-)